# Modular arithmetic basics

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$\;-6\pmod5= 4\;$ , right? First we are told that the modulus is a reminder and then for negative situations like this we are told to count backwards thru the remainders to get the right modulus. Why didn't they just stick to their original definition and have the modulus be a remainder? So that -6(mod)4 would be 1 or -1 either one of those would make more sense than 4.

Comment: What is certainly true is that $-6\equiv4\pmod5$.

Comment: What's the dollar sign for? And what's pmod?

Comment: @KJason Take a look to this and attached links: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I don't get it, as far as I can tell it seems like you understood my question but corrected some minor mistake in like my grammar or something. Is that the case?

Comment: @KJason I didn't even read your question (if you're addressing me). I only gave you a link for you to write correctly mathematics, as used in this site. If you write correctly you have way more chance to have your questions read and answered by other members of our community.

Comment: I am talking to you. Did you understand my question?

Answer (score 3):

One source of confusion is that there are two uses for "mod".  The one I call the "computer science mod" is a function.  You plug a number in to the "mod 5" function and the output is the remainder.  This is what's going on in your first sentence.

The second use is as a relation.  $\pmod{5}$ is used like an equal sign to show that two integers are related to each other because their difference is a multiple of $5$.  Your first sentence, in this usage, should read $-6 \equiv 4 \pmod{5}.$  In math, this second use is by far the most common.

Comment: Ok so when it is a function then -6(mod5) is 1 or -1? But when it's the other thing it's 4? Sorry if my notation is not quite right I don't know how to make a congruence sign. I'm trying to carry on without that.

Comment: $-6 \pmod{5} = -1$  in computer science notation.  In math notation, all numbers of the form $5k+4$ are equivalent, so $-6 \equiv -1 \equiv 4 \equiv 9 \equiv 104 \pmod{5}.$

Comment: Ok so, when it's a relation they are asking for the positive number less than the modulus (5 here) that is some number of 5's away from the number they give right? That's why there's weird behavior when the number they give is negative yes?

Comment: I wouldn't say that.  When it's a relation, you have a complete sentence which says "$a$ and $b$ differ by a multiple of $5$."  $a$ and $b$ could be anywhere on the integer number line.  Nothing is "asked for" here.  It's a statement about two numbers.

Comment: Oh really? The whole reason I asked the question is because a Kahn academy lesson asked me that question and the answer they wanted was definitely 4.

Comment: They're not using the "relation", but the "function".

Comment: But then the answer they would've wanted would be -1 wouldn't it?

Comment: No.  They want the remainder from the Division Algorithm.  In $b = qa+r,$ the DA wants $0\leq r <a$.  So they want the "least nonnegative" value.

Comment: Sorry I meant to thank you yesterday for all the answers